# How to apply TDD to web API development

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest, tdd

I'm designing a web service running on Google App Engine that scrapes a number of websites and presents their data via a RESTful interface. Based on some background reading, I think I'd like to attempt Test Driven Development (TDD) and develop my tests before I write any business code.

My problem is caused by the fact that my list of scraped elements includes timetables and other records that change quite frequently. The limit of my knowledge on TDD is that you write tests that examine the results of code execution and compare these results to a hardcoded result set. Seeing as the data set changes frequently, this method seems impossible. Assuming that this is true, what would be the best approach to test such an API? How would a large-scale web API be tested (Twitter, Google, Netflix etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choose the type of test:

1. [Unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) just test proper operation of your modules (units). You provide input data and test that code outputs proper results. If there are system dependent classes you try to [mock them](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or in case of GAE services, you use google provided [local services](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting). Unit tests can be run locally on your machine or on [CI servers](http://jenkins-ci.org/). There are two popular unit test libs for java: [Junit & TestNG](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/).
2. Integration tests check that various modules (internal & external) work together - they basically check that APIs between modules are working. They are usually run on real servers and call real external services. They are technology specific and are harder to run.

In your case, I'd go with unit tests and provide sets of different input data which you logic should parse and act upon. Since your flow is pretty simple (load data from fixed Url, parse it) you could also embed loading of real data into unit tests (we do this when we parse external sources).

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing you could easily find yourself writing integration tests.  If your aim is to test the logic for processing what is returned from the scraped data (e.g. you know that you are going to get a timetable in a specific format coming in and you now have logic to process that data) you will need to create a SEAM between your web services logic and your processing logic.  Once you have done this you should be able to mock the data that is returned from the web service call to always return the same table data and then you can write consistent unit tests against it.

```
    public class ScrapingService : IScrapingService
    {
       public string Scrape(string url)
       {// scraping logic}
    }

    public interface IScrapingService
    {
       string Scrape(string url);
    }


   public class ScrapingProcessor
   {
     private IScrapingService _scrapingService
     // inject the dependency
     pubilc ScrapingProcessor(IScrapingService scrapingService)
     {
       _scrapingService = scrapingService;
     }

     public void Process(string url)
     {

       var scrapedData = _scrapingService.Scrape(url)
       // now process the scrapedData
     }


   }
```

To test you can now create a FakeScrapingService that implements the IScrapingService interface and then return whatever data you like from the Scrape method.  There are some very good Mocking frameworks out there that make this type of thing easy.  My personal favorite is NSubstitue.

I hope this explanation helps.